# Changing the text in a programatically text field

Tags: swift, macos, textfield

I'm creating text fields programatically inside a scroll view
these are spaced out and filled with numbers. I would like the option to change the numbers at any point. I can obviously re-run the code changing for example

```
String (i+1)
```

to

```
String (i+7)
```

But this just creates another text box over the original. Is there a way to either delete the original text boxes before creating new ones. Or edit the text inside the original boxes. I obviously do not have an outlet as they are created programatically.

Thank you for your time

xcode 8.1 swift 3.0 for OSX not IOS

```
for i in 0..<18 {
    let barNumberTextColor = NSColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
    let barNumberTextFont = NSFont(name: "Lucida Grande Bold", size: 12.0)
    barNumberTextField.font = barNumberTextFont
    barNumberTextField.textColor = barNumberTextColor
    barNumberTextField = NSTextField(labelWithString: String (i+1))
    barNumberTextField.frame = NSMakeRect(CGFloat(i)*320,3,30,20)
    if (i >= 0 && i < 16) {
        self.addSubview(barNumberTextField)
    }

}//eo for
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing textfield from scroll view:

```
self.barNumberTextField.removeFromSuperview()
```

Changing textFieldValue:

```
self.barNumberTextField.stringValue = "New string"
```

Answer (score 1):

In the loop you can add a tag to the TextField, like this:

`barNumberTextField.tag = i + 1`

Then, when you need to change its content you can capture the TextField by its tag using:

`let myTextField = self.viewWithTag(x)`
where x is the tag of the textfield you need to edit.

At this point this will solve your issue: `myTextField.text = "whatever"`